# Super basic question: OpenGL version/install issue

Tags: opengl

I'm running a Python program whose GUI uses OpenGL. I'm getting all sorts of graphics error messages. I want to check the OpenGL version to make sure it's all good, but the OpenGL Extensions Viewer doesn't work. Even as admin, the extensions viewer just fails when I try to open it (and the install fails when I'm not admin).

So, how do I access info about OpenGL's current status on my machine without using that program? I looked all over and didn't see any real alternatives. I'm using Windows 7, Intel Xeon CPU, X5680 3.33GHz (x2), 24 GB RAM, NVIDIA Quadro 4000.

Keep in mind that I'm not an OpenGL programmer -- I work in Python and I use PyQt etc. So, I'd like to find a solution to this without needing a Visual tutorial...

Thanks, and sorry if this question is too basic/in the wrong place!

Comment: Just checking: do you have updated graphics drivers installed? And you're not using remote desktop or anything? Do other graphics applications work (e.g. 3D games) on the machine?

Comment: I very recently updated the NVIDIA drivers (version 376.62). I'm not using a remote desktop, and it's a work machine so I don't know if other programs work. The program I'm trying to run does display properly at first, but then crashes.

Comment: Can anyone help me out with this?